# How to executing a callback function with multiple threads in ROS2

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-humble

I have a camera_node publishing image to processer_node, images are published faster than they are processed.

When a new image appears in my image queue but the previous image is still processing, split a thread to bind a callback function to process the new image.

Is there any way to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can process multiple msgs coming on the same topic in multiple threads and you do not need to handle thread spinning, it can be done using `callback group` and `executor` functionalities of ros2. To achieve this you can follow these steps

- Define a [multithreaded executor](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Concepts/About-Executors.html#callback-groups:%7E:text=The-,Multi%2DThreaded%20Executor,-creates%20a%20configurable) in your main function

> `rclcpp::executors::MultiThreadedExecutor executor;`

- Add your node to this executor

> `executor->add_node(node);`

- Now inside your node define a reentrant callback group (this allows parallel execution) and give this callback group in your topic subscription

  - `my_callback_group = create_callback_group(rclcpp::CallbackGroupType::Reentrant);`
  - `rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions options;`
  - `options.callback_group = my_callback_group;`
  - `my_subscription = create_subscription<type>("/topic",rclcpp::SensorDataQoS(),callback, options);`

This should work for your use case. For further understanding check out the [executor](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Concepts/About-Executors.html#callback-groups) concept on ros 2 wiki.

Comment: thanks for you answer, I have tried this, but do not work.

I create a sub and a pub in a node. The callback of the sub just print a debug info and sleep 5s. And I use a for to publish msg for five times. The expected status is the sub_callback print five info without delay. However, the actual situation is that there is a five-second delay for every message I output

Comment: I've seen a lot of articles about the multithreaded executor, but most of the descriptions of it are multithreaded execution of different callbacks within a node, are you sure he can multithread a single callback?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Did you used Reentran callback group type or mutually exclusive?

Comment: thanks, it is something wrong in my code, I fix it and it work well now.

Comment: But when two or more callbacks operate the same variables within class in the same time, there is no error. Did ros2 solver this itself? How did ros2 does this, a simple lock or other things?

Comment: Also, I'm using component to make image_pub_node and image_sub_node in the same process, that they can open use_intra_process_comms to use zero-copy. But component is a SingleThreadedExecutor, can i set it to MultiThread?

Comment: 'How did ros2 does this, a simple lock or other things?' : I am not sure if ros2 does anything for this internally. if both callbacks are operating on the same variable then there will be some race conditions and you'll have to take care of it yourself.

Comment: ' But component is a SingleThreadedExecutor, can i set it to MultiThread?' : I am pretty sure this an be done. you should go through the documentation. In my understanding even if a node has a default executor you can still create another executor and add your callbacks to it and spin it independently in a thread.